# How can I cut off the first row and first columns of a dataframe (headers, respectively)?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am reading in some data about distances of cities with Pandas and I only need the distances as numbers for my calculation as a matrix. Panda does import everything fine but I still have the city names as Headers. This will be used for classic Multi-Dimensional Scaling.

My CSV (in a short version) looks like this:

```
"","Athens","Barcelona","Brussels"
"Athens",0,3313,2963
"Barcelona",3313,0,1318
"Brussels",2963,1318,0
```

Which is fine but in my function I only need the values like this:

```
0,3313,2963
3313,0,1318
2963,1318,0
```

I can't get only this matrix out of the CSV above. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok this is what we have

```
a = StringIO(""""","Athens","Barcelona","Brussels"
"Athens",0,3313,2963
"Barcelona",3313,0,1318
"Brussels",2963,1318,0""")

df = pd.read_csv(a,sep=',',engine='python')
```

print(df)

```
  Unnamed: 0  Athens  Barcelona  Brussels
0     Athens       0       3313      2963
1  Barcelona    3313          0      1318
2   Brussels    2963       1318         0

df.loc[:,'Athens':].values
```

**Output**

```
array([[   0, 3313, 2963],
       [3313,    0, 1318],
       [2963, 1318,    0]])
```

---

pd.to_csv

```
[i for i in df.loc[:,'Athens':].to_csv(header=None).split('\n') if i ]


['0,0,3313,2963', '1,3313,0,1318', '2,2963,1318,0']
```

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly (the other answers are kinda similiar, thanks to them aswell). One more question: Is there a possibility to dynamically chose the 'Athens'? Maybe like df.col[1]?

Comment: you mean getting the Athens column values.. doing like df['Athens']

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
data=""""","Athens","Barcelona","Brussels"
"Athens",0,3313,2963
"Barcelona",3313,0,1318
"Brussels",2963,1318,0"""
```

---

```
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data),index_col=0) #replace pd.compat..() with filename
df.to_numpy() #df.values
```

---

```
array([[   0, 3313, 2963],
   [3313,    0, 1318],
   [2963, 1318,    0]], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 1):

First we read your data in as csv, convert it to an array and slice of the first column:

```
df = pd.read_csv(a).to_numpy()[:, 1:]
```

---

```
array([[0, 3313, 2963],
       [3313, 0, 1318],
       [2963, 1318, 0]], dtype=object)
```

---

**Note** I read your csv in as `a` like following:

```
a = StringIO('''
"","Athens","Barcelona","Brussels"
"Athens",0,3313,2963
"Barcelona",3313,0,1318
"Brussels",2963,1318,0
''')
```